# Code Chef DSA Learning Series : Multiple of 3 Multhree

Tags: c++, data-structures

My algorithm is different from question previously uploaded so please don't close it by seeing the same topic of the question

Consider a very long K-digit number N with digits d0, d1, ..., dK-1 (in decimal notation; d0 is the most significant and dK-1 the least significant digit). This number is so large that we can't give it to you on the input explicitly; instead, you are only given its starting digits and a way to construct the remainder of the number.

Specifically, you are given d0 and d1; for each i ≥ 2, di is the sum of all preceding (more significant) digits, modulo 10 — more formally, the following formula must hold:

Determine if N is a multiple of 3.
Input

```
The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first and only line of each test case contains three space-separated integers K, d0 and d1.
```

Output

For each test case, print a single line containing the string "YES" (without quotes) if the number N is a multiple of 3 or "NO" (without quotes) otherwise.

Example

Input:

```
3
5 3 4
13 8 1
760399384224 5 1
```

Output:

```
NO
YES
YES
```

Explanation

Example case 1: The whole number N is 34748, which is not divisible by 3, so the answer is NO.

Example case 2: The whole number N is 8198624862486, which is divisible by 3, so the answer is YES.

[question link](https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA01/problems/MULTHREE)

**I am not able to understand whats wrong with this code,
it doesn't work with this test case:**

`input : 1 760399384224 5 1`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
// your code goes here
int t;
std::cin >> t;
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    long long k,d0,d1,sum=0,x;
    std::cin >> k>>d0>>d1;
    sum=d0+d1;
    for(;k>2;k--)
    {
        x=sum;
        int z=x%10;
        if(z==0)
            break;
        sum=sum+z;
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
    /*if(sum>10)
    {
        long long a=sum/10;
        long long b=sum%10;
        sum=a+b;
    }*/
    if(sum%3==0)
        sum=0;
    if(sum%3==0)
    {
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you print the `sum` but the output should only be `YES` and `NO`. That can be the reason for getting the solution rejected. What output do you get for that test case? What output did you expect instead?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 that is not the issue i printed it so that i could know that is the algorithm giving me correct sum

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks bro i will definitely try to learn it